# Value of type 'MagnificationGesture' has no member 'onChanged'

Tags: swiftui

Not sure if I am just doing something wrong or if it is a bug

This code will not compile in Xcode 13.2.1

compile error
Value of type 'MagnificationGesture' has no member 'onChanged'

```
struct MagnificationGesture: View {
@State private var currentAmount = 0.0
@State private var finalAmount = 1.0

var body: some View {
    Text("Hello, World!")
        .font(.title)
        .padding(25)
        .background(.blue)
        .cornerRadius(10)
        .scaleEffect(finalAmount + currentAmount)
        .gesture(
            MagnificationGesture()
                .onChanged { amount in
                    currentAmount = amount
                }
                .onEnded { amount in
                    finalAmount += currentAmount
                    currentAmount = 0
                }
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've named your `View` `MagnificationGesture` -- that takes over that name in the current namespace (your module). Then, you try to use SwiftUI's `MagnificationGesture` inside `gesture()` and the compiler thinks you're referring to *your* `MagnificationGesture`.

The simplest solution is to rename your `View` so that there isn't a collision between the names:

```
struct MagnificationGestureView: View { //<-- Here
    @State private var currentAmount = 0.0
    @State private var finalAmount = 1.0
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .font(.title)
            .padding(25)
            .background(.blue)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .scaleEffect(finalAmount + currentAmount)
            .gesture(
                MagnificationGesture()
                    .onChanged { amount in
                        currentAmount = amount
                    }
                    .onEnded { amount in
                        finalAmount += currentAmount
                        currentAmount = 0
                    }
            )
    }
}
```

Technically, you could also solve this by explicitly using the `SwiftUI` module name (see below), but this is much more confusing later on -- the better practice is just to avoid using the same name as existing types from other modules.

```
SwiftUI.MagnificationGesture()
    .onChanged { amount in
        currentAmount = amount
    }
```